# Is there any way to use a single template and dynamically populate the template?

Tags: angularjs, html, routes, angular-routing, angularjs-templates

Is there any way to use a single template and dynamically populate the template? http://jsfiddle.net/cmckeachie/mtV62/light/

```
var routingExample = angular.module('FunnyAnt.Examples.Routing', []);
routingExample.controller('HomeController', function ($scope) {});
routingExample.controller('AboutController', function ($scope) {});

routingExample.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'embedded.home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    }).
    when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'embedded.about.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });
});
```

say I want to use embedded.home.html template to pass "Home" and "About" values dynamically. Please help as I am new to AngularJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can do that using stateParams(ui-router) or routeParams for(ngRoute).

Stateparams as follows

```
$stateProvider
    .state('contacts.detail', {
        url: "/contacts/:contactId",
        templateUrl: 'contacts.detail.html',
        controller: function ($stateParams) {
           // other stuff
        }
    })
```

sample state params could be like this

```
// Your $stateParams object could be
{ id:'123', type:'default', repeat:'0', from:'there', to:'here' }
```

using route provider you can do as follows

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/home:id:type', {
        templateUrl: 'embedded.home.html',
        controller: 'Ctrl1'
    }).
    when('/about:id:type', {
        templateUrl: 'embedded.about.html',
        controller: 'Ctrl2'
    });

routingExample.controller("Ctrl1", function($scope, $routeParams) {
  console.log($routeParams.id);
  console.log($routeParams.type);
  // do other stuff
});
```

[Look at this blog for more details.](http://www.ekiras.com/2015/07/angularjs-routeparams-with-ngroute.html)

Comment: Thanks @Ekansh! Do you mind providing a working fiddle so that I understand better?

Comment: look at this blog http://www.ekiras.com/2015/07/angularjs-routeparams-with-ngroute.html